# Inputs and user input validation

Tags: python, input, raw-input

I have researched this question on here I have found similar question but this is different. I need to validate user input in the piece of code I am working on needs to print an error if the user input is either under 0 (This I have working fine) and print an error if the input is non-numeric here is where my problems are. If i use input rather than raw_input i get an error:

```
NameError name 'Whatever I type in' is not defined
```

What I tried so far:

Casting the variable as an integer and tried using the isNaN function but that failed miserably and finally going around the problem using ifs and elses. this is the code that works so far.

```
def pints_to_litres():
    pints = 0
    pints = input("Please enter the amount of Imperial Pints you would like converted into Litres >>>")
    litres = pints * float(0.568261)
    litres = "%.2f" % litres
    print (""+str(pints)+ " Pint(s) is equal to " +str(litres)+ " Litre(s)")
    if (pints < 0):
        print("Invalid Input! Try Again")
        pints_to_litres()
```

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Not sure why the edit, this is Python code.

Comment: why aren't you using `raw_input`?

Comment: I still get errors with raw_input "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Comment: Why are you *trying* to use `input()`? Did you read [what it does](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)?

Comment: I also thought that input is the preferred one due to the variable being supposed to be a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here I improved your code:

```
def pints_to_litres():
    over = False
    while not over:
        try:
            pints = int(raw_input("Please enter the amount of Imperial Pints you would like converted into Litres >>>"))
            litres = pints * float(0.568261)
            print (""+str(pints)+ " Pint(s) is equal to " +str(litres)+ " Litre(s)")
            if (pints < 0):
                print("Invalid Input! Try Again")
            else:
                over = True
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Input! Try Again")
```

- useless setting of `pints` before overwriting it with `raw_input` ;
- changed use of `input` in favor of `raw_input` designed for that purpose ;
- if the string is invalid, it throws a `ValueError` at the time of the `int()` conversion of pints and loops again ;
- if the value is too low, it loops again ;
- As you can see, I also changed your recursive call to the function, as if the user always fails, you'll end up smashing the function stack limit, and have a failure.

Comment: Thank You! This is perfect and works perfectly, Best of all I can now see where I went wrong so Many Thanks :)

Comment: LOL. As a answer once goes, “Who would fail to type in a number 999999 times?” “Who knows? Maybe you will.” BTW, th error is called a RuntimeError.

Comment: it's not because it's unlikely to happen that it **cannot** happen! You never know how you'll use a code in the future, and you should always have it work as best as it can be!

Answer (score 1):

```
pints = raw_input("Please enter the amount of Imperial Pints you would like converted into Litres >>>")
try:
     pints = float(pints)
except ValueError:
     print("Invalid Input! Try Again")
     pints_to_litres()
```

then continue with the code

Comment: it's bad programing to recurse over a function, without doing a proper recursion.

Comment: agreed.  your answer is much better.  i was making as little change to op's code as possible

Comment: Thanks for your help honi I managed to fix it with @zmo 's fix. Thank you for trying to help me, I appreciate it greatly :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
try:
    pints = float(raw_input("Please enter the amount of Imperial Pints you would like converted into Litres >>>\n"))
    # Calculation ...
except ValueError:
    print "Error"
```

Comment: Thank you josip_grg It has now been fixed. Thank you for your help. As a beginner at this any help is both helpful and teaches me something.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the input is a digit bu using `.isdigit()` try this

```
entry =raw_input("Please enter the amount of Imperial Pints you would like converted into Litres >>>")
        if (not( entry.isdigit())):
                print "not a number"
                pints_to_litres()
        else:
                 pints=(int)(entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.lang.Throwable;

public class Paint1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        double wallHeight = 0.0;
        double wallWidth = 0.0;
        double wallArea = 0.0;
        double gallonsPaintNeeded = 0.0;
        
        final double squareFeetPerGallons = 350.0;
        
        // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
        // Prompt user to input wall's height
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
                wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
                if (wallHeight <= 0) {
                    throw new Throwable();
                }
            } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                scnr.next(); // cleared the bad value from the scanner
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid input of a number. No alphabet characters.");
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive number greater than 0.");
            }
        } while (wallHeight <= 0);

        // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
        // Prompt user to input wall's width
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter wall width (feet): ");
                wallWidth = scnr.nextDouble();
                if (wallWidth <= 0) {
                    throw new Throwable();
                }
            } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                scnr.next(); // clear the bad value from the scanner
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid input of a number. No alphabet characters.");
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive number greater than 0.");
            }
        } while (wallWidth <= 0); 

        // Calculate and output wall area
        wallArea = wallHeight * wallWidth;
        System.out.println("Wall area: " +  wallArea + " square feet");

        // Calculate and output the amount of paint (in gallons) needed to paint the wall
        gallonsPaintNeeded = wallArea/squareFeetPerGallons;
        System.out.println("Paint needed: " + gallonsPaintNeeded + " gallons");
//This was an interesting assignment, was able to get direction and assistance with this. 
    }
}
```